# Extend Official Display Connections

Tags: display, video, peripherals, cable

Is there a type of extender for the official Pi display connections? I don't mean the 15 pin FFC, but the two directly on the display. I'm mounting the driver board separately from the display in a way that the cables would be flexed a lot, so I'd rather replace an extension FFC than the whole display.

If not, is there a way to make the display+driver board thinner?
[image]

Comment: There are a lot more than two wires going into the display. The two you're seeing are likely the backlight.

Comment: Could you post a photo showing the cables you want to extend? But I can say upfront that I doubt it will be realistically possible. I would start by looking for a different display that fits your project, or for a bigger case.

Comment: Just added the pic of the two connectors. I'm 3d-printing the case myself, so I could make it bigger if I need to, but I'm trying to make it thin as it's already got thick components in it. Also, I'll very likely use the Pi display whether I can flatten it or not, since there's already huge support for it online.